# Get Code Coverage from utPLSQL within Azure DevOps Pipeline?

Tags: oracle, azure-devops, utplsql

I'm using utPLSQL 3.1.12.3589 on an Oracle 19c database.
The business logic to be tested is deployed in schema BUSINESS_LOGIC, the unit tests are deployed in schema UNIT_TESTS.

When I collect the code coverage within an Azure DevOps pipeline it seems to pick up only that from schema UNIT_TESTS. How can I get the coverage from schema BUSINESS_LOGIC?

utPLSQL-cli is called from a Powershell script (connection parameters are in the variables):

```
$argstr = @("run $db_user/$db_pw@$db_conn", "-f=UT_JUNIT_REPORTER", "-o=dbtest.xml", "-f=UT_COVERAGE_COBERTURA_REPORTER", "-o=dbcoverage.xml", "-f=UT_COVERAGE_HTML_REPORTER", "-o=html_coverage/coverage.html")
Start-Process -FilePath "\\my-server\utPLSQL-cli\bin\utplsql.bat" -ArgumentList $argstr -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

This is necessary because the tests are integrated in an Azure DevOps pipeline.
Thus the recommended approach to set the coverage does not work for me (
http://www.utplsql.org/utPLSQL/latest/userguide/coverage.html):

```
exec ut.run(ut_varchar2_list('BUSINESS_LOGIC'), ut_coverage_html_reporter());
```

I simply don't know where I could place the above statement to run the tests, gather the code coverage and report back to DevOps? I thought the command for the appropriate schema must be passed to the utPLSQL-cli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that I used an up-to-date version of utPLSQL but not of utPLSQL-cli. Version 3.1.9 now supports a command line parameter to pass a list of coverage schemes: `coverage-schemes`.

This can be added to the argument list:

```
$argstr = @("run $db_user/$db_pw@$db_conn", ..., "--coverage-schemes=BUSINESS_LOGIC")
```

Now the coverage from BUSINESS_LOGIC is retrieved!